# User Input being skipped

Tags: c

still making my way through C Programming Absolute Beginner's Guide.

I am at the example about Structures and I cannot figure out what is going wrong. When I compile and run the code, the first two questions run fine, but after it prompts for "How much did the book cost?", when I enter the input for this one, the next two questions get posted together. I have no idea why. I think I have the code written as shown in the book. I have read online that gets is not code but I am not sure why at this point. Any guidance would once again be greatly appreciated!

```
//This header file defines a structure for information about a book

struct bookInfo {
    char title[40];
    char author[25];
    float price;
    int pages;
};




/*This program gets the bookInfo structure by including structurePractice.h
and asks the user to fill in three structures and then prints them*/

//First, include the header file

#include "structurePractice.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ctr;
    struct bookInfo books[3]; //Array of 3 structure variables

    //Get information about each book from the user

    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
    {
        printf("What is the name of the book #%d?\n", (ctr+1));
        gets(books[ctr].title);
        puts("Who's is the author? ");
        gets(books[ctr].author);
        puts("How much did the book cost? ");
        scanf(" $%f", &books[ctr].price);
        puts("How many pages are in the book? ");
        scanf(" %d", &books[ctr].pages);
        getchar(); //Clears last newline for next loop
    }

    //Print a header line and then loop through and print the info

    printf("\n\nHere is the collection of books: \n");
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
    {
        printf("#%d: %s by %s", (ctr+1), books[ctr].title, books[ctr].author);
        printf("\nIt is %d pages and costs $%.2f", books[ctr].pages, books[ctr].price);
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: If it teaches use of `gets()`, get a new book. That function is obsolete and should never be used.

Comment: Are you typing a `$` before the price?

Comment: I am not, should I be? I assumed no because it was in the code

Comment: The problem appears to be with scanf based on what I am seeing, but obviously I may very well be wrong on that front

Comment: [`scanf` has many problems](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). And I agree with Barmar, if a book written in 2013 is still using `gets`, "gets" rid of the book.

Comment: Thanks. I am almost finished it at this point. I read that it was a good place to jump in if you had absolutely no experience with C, perhaps that was outdated advice..

Comment: The format string `" $%f"` requires a `$` before the number.

Comment: That means that the format of the input is a `$` before a floating point number.

Comment: Simple as that. Thank you!

Comment: I'll get this figured out.. I am disheartened about spending the time on this book now though. Time to move on I guess!

Comment: "Absolute Beginner's Guide" Maybe it means _by_ an absolute beginner? :) But don't worry too much about how to use various functions in `stdio.h` overall, it's an awful library overall and often banned in real production code. Also, console applications are becoming increasingly rare. There's just a bunch of stubborn Unix conservatives that cling on to them still. It's far more important to understand programming overall, than learning some specific I/O lib.

Comment: That’s a great way to look at time invested in this book, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `scanf`.

```
scanf(" $%f", &books[ctr].price);
        ^
        |
        here
```

That says you want a `$` followed by a decimal number. If the user does not input a dollar sign, scanf will read nothing. The input will remain on the input buffer. It will be read by the next `scanf`.

This is one of the [many problems with `scanf`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). Because `scanf` mixes up reading input with parsing input, if the input does not match the expected format it will remain in the input buffer. Instead, read and parse separately with `fgets` (not [`gets`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getsvsfgets.html)) and `sscanf`. It's also important to check that the input was read else `books[ctr].price` will contain garbage.

```
// Declare a buffer once outside the loop. Reuse it for each fgets call.
// BUFSIZ is a constant for the natural I/O buffer size of your platform.
char buf[BUFSIZ];

puts("How much did the book cost? ");
// Read only as much as the buffer can handle. This is what makes fgets safe,
// and gets unsafe.
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);

// sscanf returns the number of items matched. Check if they all matched.
if( sscanf(buf, " %f", &books[ctr].price) != 1) {
    printf("Sorry, '%s' doesn't look like a price.", buf);

    // Set it to something or else it will be garbage.
    books[ctr].price = 0;
}
```

A real program would loop until it gets valid input. The important thing is to read the buffer, then parse it, and check if the parsing worked. Later on you might write a little function to package up this prompting code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have come to the realization that I need to move on to a better, more up to date, resource. I don't feel like it was a complete waste, but it is disheartening none the less.

Comment: @apreynolds1989 Unfortunately a lot of programming books are like that. I doubt it was a waste, you'll have learned a lot, but also some bad things. I liked Learn C The Hard Way both for being up to date, and not afraid to address hard but necessary problems.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that one.